# PHP not running after Upgrade Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have upgraded my Ubuntu server to 22.04.1. Everything else is working fine but php simply does not run! I tried to visit my website and all I get is php source code.
For example, mydomain.com/info.php shows me the code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

I restarted all apache services - nothing changed!
php -v on terminal shows this (everything OK):

PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Jul 21 2022 12:10:37) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.1.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Any idea?

Comment: it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-but-the-code-shows-in-the-browser-source-code

Answer (score 5):

You could also just have added the symlinks to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled for the php8.1.load and php8.1.conf files found in /etc/apache2/mods-available

1. cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
2. ln -s ../mods-available/php8.1.load php8.1.load
3. ln -s ../mods-available/php8.1.conf php8.1.conf
4. restart apache

Comment: I had the exact same problem as OP. This solution fixed the issue on my side.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was php 8.1 which cause this issue. Before the upgrade I had php 7.4 and everything was fine, so I removed php 8.1